# how to return current datetime of the server and pass it through ajax to my jquery script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display the current time of the server on my webpage. I know that jquery works on client's side, so I want to import the datetime from my server, for example using ajax.
I found the following code:

```
try {
  var date = new Date($.ajax({'type': 'HEAD', 'url': 'timeoftheserver.php'}).getResponseHeader('Date'));
}
catch(err) { 
  var date = null;
}
```

but how can I prepare a php page that will return me that particular time?
Thanks!

Comment: Write date("Y-m-d H:i:s a") in php page and return it or you can echo it \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your timeoftheserver.php:

```
<?php
   echo date('D, d M y H:i:s')." +0000";
?>
```